# How to enable rotation of log files for celeryd with djcelery?

Tags: celery

I have below settings in my celery configuration file:

1. CELERYD_LOG_DEBUG='FALSE'
2. CELERYD_LOG_FILE=r'/var/log/celery/celeryd.log'
3. CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="ERROR"

I looked at the settings file of the celery and there is no option to specify the log file size limit in the configuration. Even the code looks like its using the StreamHandler instead of the RotationHandler class. Any clues/hints ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

For log rotation on Ubuntu, if you have your celery log in /var/log/celery/
celeryd.log you can use a configuration like the one above to do
weekly log rotation with /etc/logrotate.d/.

```
/var/log/celery/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    copytruncate
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I didn't exactly work for me. It does create daily files (in my case) but after the log is rotated, even though the log file still exists, it stays empty until I reastart celeryd and celerybeat. Is there a signal I can send the process to let it know the file "changed"?

Comment: You must use celery 2.2.5 or higher, there the log-rotate should work without problems.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/changelog.html#v225-news

Comment: From my requirements.txt:
celery==2.5.3
django-celery==2.5.5

My startup command: python manage.py celeryd_detach --pidfile={project_location}/celeryd.pid --autoscale=10,10 --autoreload --loglevel=INFO --logfile={log_location}/celeryd.log --pythonpath=/usr/share/pyshared

After the log gets rotated it stays empty until I kill the previous job and restarts it.

Comment: Weird!
You tried to disable the autoreload and see if the logrotate works?
It's possible that some reload code functionality create problems,

Comment: Updated link to 2.2 changelog below. As of 2.2, Celery uses a `WatchedFileHandler`, which will notice when the log files are rotated and update its file handlers appropriately without needing to be restarted. Thanks @MauroRocco!


http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/changelog-2.2.html?highlight=logrotate

Comment: What about for windows OS @mauro

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `[WatchedFileHandler][1]`.  It notices that a file has been truncated or changed otherwise and reopens the file.  Note you must set [CELERY_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER](http://celery.github.com/celery/configuration.html#celeryd-hijack-root-logger) = False and then setup this logger yourself, and do logging.getLogger('custom_logger') inside the tasks yourself.  See [this post](http://loose-bits.com/2010/12/celery-logging-with-python-logging.html) about how Celery's builtin logging configuration is not flexible and for fine-grained control.